# How can I create a contenteditable <div> in GWT on the client side?

Tags: gwt, dom, widget, contenteditable

I'm trying to create a custom widget in GWT that creates a div with contenteditable=true inside of it. The problem is that when I create this div and I initialize this widget, the div does not have the contenteditable property.

my code:

```
public MyWidget(){
    FlowPanel panel = new FlowPanel();
    initWidget(panel);


    HTML div = new HTML("<div id=\"my-div\" contenteditable=true></div>");
    div.setText("hello there");
    div.addHandler(new MyWidgetKeyDownHandler(), KeyDownEvent.getType());

    mDiv = div;
    panel.add(div);
}
```

But when I run the code and I inspect the source, I see this:

```
<div>
 <div class="gwt-HTML">hello there</div>
</div>
```

So it looks like it's missing the contenteditable tag as well as the id. What am I doing wrong here? How can I create this contenteditable div widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
div.getElement().setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
```

I would work around your requirement for a specific id.  You can set one with ensureDebugId but you might find it simpler to do without it.